# How to convert unknown values in column to row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to convert unknown values in column to row with fixed column and sum value in another column in SQL Server?

This example

```
   | Id | Date | Amount1 | Amount2
   +----+------+---------+--------
   | 1  | 2018 | 1000    | 100
   | 2  | 2018 | 2000    | 200
   | 2  | 2018 | 3000    | 300
   | 1  | 2019 | 4000    | 400
   | 1  | 2019 | 5000    | 500
   | .. | .... | ....    | ...
```

I want this

```
| Id | 2018Amount1 | 2018Amount2 | 2019Amount1 | 2019Amount2 | ...
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------
| 1  |    1000     |     100     |   9000      |   900       | ...
| 2  |    5000     |     500     |   0         |   0         | ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic pivot

```
DECLARE @ColName NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
SELECT @ColName = @ColName + ', '+ ColName
FROM (  SELECT  DISTINCT  QUOTENAME( CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'Amount1') 
            + ', ' + QUOTENAME(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'Amount2') ColName FROM TestTable )T

SET @ColName = STUFF (@ColName,1,1,'')

DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Id, CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(4)) + ''Amount1'' AS [Date], Amount1 AS Amount FROM TestTable
    UNION 
    SELECT Id, CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(4)) + ''Amount2'' [Date], Amount2 AS Amount FROM TestTable
) SRC
PIVOT(SUM(Amount) FOR Date IN (' + @ColName+ ') ) AS PVT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlText
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation :

```
select Id, 
       sum( case when Date = 2018 then Amount1 end ) as "2018Amount1",
       sum( case when Date = 2018 then Amount2 end ) as "2018Amount2",
       sum( case when Date = 2019 then Amount1 end ) as "2019Amount1",
       sum( case when Date = 2019 then Amount2 end ) as "2019Amount2" 
  from tab
 group by Id
```

Comment: but values are unkown

Comment: Barbaros Özhan thanks but I think pivot make this

Comment: @super.Omar welcome Omar, yes we have a method using `pivot` keyword but also that needs explicit specification for all of the returning columns.

Comment: @super.Omar Larnu suggests a better, dynamical way.

Comment: **The basis of the problem I have this**

 | Id | Date | Amount1
   +----+------+--------
   | 1  | 2018 |  3000    
   | 1  | 2019 | -3000    
   | 1  | 2019 |  3000    
   | ..  | ....   | ....    


**How I Get this**
| Id | Date2018 | Date2019
+----+------+--------
| 1   |  3000       |  0
| ..  | ....          | ....    

**I don't need this**
| Id | Date2018 | Date2019
+----+------+--------
| 1  |  0       |  3000    
| ..  | ....          | ....

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thank you master, I confused the phrases :)